# How to access data in a promise angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I wanted to access a data in promise. I have the following code :

```
function getUser() {
Users.query({username: usersOnline}).$promise.then(function (results) {
  console.log(results);
    $scope.userss = results;
    return results;
  }, function(error) {
  // console.log(error);
   //$scope.meetups = [];
});
//$scope.userss[0].username='oui';
}
$scope.lol=getUser();
$scope.lol.then(function(user){
console.log(user.username);
});
```

But i get an error saying cant find property then of undefined can you help

Comment: you are returning `undefined` from your `getUser` function.

Comment: You're missing a `return` statement in `getUser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return `Users.query` promise from `getUser` user function, as caller function is performing `.then`(expecting promise) there.

```
function getUser() {
//return promise here
    return Users.query({username: usersOnline}).$promise
    //other code as is

}
```

Comment: @MikyasTADESSE Glad to help you, Thanks ;)